# Concatenate/merge rows for one column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following Dataframe in Pandas:

```
C1    C2   C3   C4 
2021  4    1X   "First text "
2021  NaN  NaN  "continued"
2021  NaN  NaN  "still Continued"
2021  5    1Y   "second text"
2021  NaN  NaN  "continued"
```

I want to convert this to a Dataframe as follows:

```
C1    C2   C3   C4 
2021  4    1X   "First text continued still continued"
2021  5    1Y   "second text continued"
```

That is, I want to merge the rows of `C4` column into a single row until a new value comes in `C2` and `C3` columns. Is there any efficient way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `ffill` before `groupby`

```
out = df.ffill().groupby(['C1','C2','C3'],as_index=False)['C4'].agg(' '.join)
Out[49]: 
     C1   C2  C3                                        C4
0  2021  4.0  1X  "Firsttext" "continued" "stillContinued"
1  2021  5.0  1Y                  "secondtext" "continued"
```

Comment: This is very excellent approach! I think OP wants the C4 to have the strings in a sentence without many opening and closing quotations.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! However, the order got messed up for a large file. I had to use `sort_values()` to get the original order (original dataframe was already following some order).